# Is there a newer alternative to WideImage?

Tags: php, wideimage

I have been recommended the use of WideImage library to generate thumbnails in needed sizes, but looking at the codebase it seems to use quite a lot of deprecated functions.

What would the PHP7/2019 equivalent be?

```
 38 | ERROR | Function imagepsloadfont() is removed since PHP 7.0
 52 | ERROR | Function imagepstext() is removed since PHP 7.0
 57 | ERROR | Function imagepsfreefont() is removed since PHP 7.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/smottt/WideImage